# Introduce Google Map API to WordPress plugin "Cab Fare Calculator"

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

I would like to have information regarding the prices of the Google Maps API, which I would like to connect to a WordPress plugin "Cab Fare Calculator" if I understand correctly, the Google Map API will be free if I do not exceed more than 2500 taxi ride orders per month. If I exceed this number, will I be charged? So to have access to the Google Maps API services I must enter my bank details but I will not be billed because I benefit from a credit of 200 dollars per month. I will only be billed if I exceed 2500 taxi ride orders per month on my website, otherwise it will be free each month, right?

I just bought the free version of the plugin, and I can't write valid addresses because it say:

> "This page can't load Google Maps correctly".

I must connect the Google Maps API Key but I want to be sure that I understand correctly the rules of billing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As much as we would like to help, this place is for programming questions. If you want to have more queries about their billing, please file a support case to their billing team for better line of help. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-billing-support-as-a-billing-admin Google Maps APIs have $200 free monthly credit, so you can try it out without worrying much. And I'm not sure where you got the free 2500 taxi ride orders, but pricing is here. https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/#pricing-grid?